# send dynamically created input values to PHP using get request

Tags: php, jquery, forms, input, get

i have a form. i'm allowing the user to add extra inputs by pressing a button:

```
$('#add_multi_item').click(function(){

                $('<input />').attr({'type':'text', 'id':'response_input_' + next_add_id}).appendTo('#multi_responses');
                next_add_id++;
            });
```

and my form is being submitted like this:

```
$("#add_form").bind('submit', function(event){ 
         event.preventDefault();
         $.get('file.php', {poll_type_select: $("#poll_type_select option:selected").val(), question_input: escape($("#question_input").val()), type: "add_poll", user_id:user_id}, function(data) {
                    $('#added').show().html(data);
                    $('#added').hide(7000);
                    $('#question_input').val('');
                    loadList();
                });
    });
```

how do i add those dynamically created input values into the get request? i guess some people use name arrays for post, but can i do something similar? also i think i will have to escape() all the inputs before sending them to prevent errors when adding to the database.

one option i was thinking was to send a single value, a delimited string created using something like:

```
$("#multi_responses input").each(string+=escape($(this).val())+"delimiter");
```

but i don't know if that's the best way. and if i do that, what is a typical delimiter to use?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's right, you just have to give those inputs a `name` attribute, like:

```
$('<input />').attr({'type':'text', 'id':'response_input_' + next_add_id, 'name': 'response_input[' + next_add_id + ']'}).appendTo('#multi_responses');
```

Comment: Add use a POST instead of a GET. And allow the default form submit to do its thing.

Comment: I agree with the POST method, but actually, if vee wants to make an ajax request, the right thing to do is the prevent the form from submitting -but as jm says POST would be better.

Comment: thanks for the response. so i understand that part now, but how do i then send that name array through my get request? this doesn't work: 'multi_responses[]':$("#add_form input[name=response_input[]]").val().

Comment: and there are several reasons why i am submitting the form through ajax instead of the default: first, i don't want it to redirect to a new page and i am adding the response to a div, second, i am altering some of the fields using escape() in js, third, i am sending one of my js variables (user_id) along with the request. but in the ajax request, what is the advantage of POST over GET?

Comment: A POST request will be the most correct way to go, but there is no absolute rule that states that "POST is better than GET". That's more like a relative question, depending on every situation's characteristics. That's another discussion, I think.

Comment: In your `$.post()` (or `$.get()`)function, you can pass an object holding the data you want to send with your request. See the documentation for `serializeArray()` to have some hints on how to encode the values of the form as an object, and see the documentation for `$.get()` and `$.post()` for the `data` object.